# Mysql update auto-count by number of row updates

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm wondering if is possible to update automaticaly some number (+1) in row when this row hits update.

Similar function like auto-increment of new ID record. But depending on row changes.

```
Data sample
id ; column1; n_changes
1  ; pedro  ; 1
```

And when I do `update table set column1 = 'hugo' WHERE id = 1`

```
Data sample
id ; column1; n_changes
1  ; hugo   ; 2
```

**Of course first answer coul'd be - put update of this number into query but I have reason to try solve it on db self.
I'm using Mysql 5.6 or MariaDB.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this type of operation, a trigger is normally recommended if you want it done automatically.

However, this is easily included in the `update` itself:

```
update table
    set column1 = 'hugo',
        n_changes = n_changes + 1
    where id = 1 and column1 <> 'hugo';
```

Note the inclusion of `column1 <> 'hugo'` in the `where`.  MySQL would not actually update the record if the value does not change.  My guess is that if the value remains the same, you don't want to increment your counter either.

EDIT:

A trigger is pretty easy:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum BEFORE UPDATE ON t
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET new.n_changes = new.n_changes + 1;
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

Remember to make the `n_changes` `NOT NULL` with a default value of 0.

Comment: Yes, I knew but, it's specific,  I'm trying avoid to do any aplication modification.
To consider less evil.
How difficult is set-up trigger for my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Just increment the `n_changes` column when you do the update:

```
UPDATE table
SET
    column1 = 'hugo',
    n_changes = n_changes + 1
WHERE id = 1;
```